# Test on the difference of reciprocals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to prove that a certain series $\sum a_n$ diverges.

All I know is that the terms are positive, strictly decreasing and tend to zero.

Moreover  the two following limits hold:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow   \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow   \infty} \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}= \frac{1}{3}$$

Is there any standard test that comes to your mind?

I have been wondering if the following is true: 
if $\sum a_n$ converges then $\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}$ is unbounded

Not sure if this holds but it would solve the problem as well.

Thank you very much for any hint/suggestion you might have!

Comment: Your second limit indicates that the series basically behaves like the harmonic series in the limit. You should be able to bound it from below by an appropriate multiple of $\frac 1n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  here is a heuristic argument:

Using a telescoping series, $\frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{a_1} \approx \frac{n}{3}$.  Taking reciprocals, 
$a_n \approx \frac{3}{n}$, so the series behaves like the harmonic series, which diverges.  You must fill in some missing steps, probably by showing your series is greater than some constant multiple of the harmonic series.

To make this more rigorous, one way would be to use the fact that $\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} < \frac{1}{2}$ for $n \geq N$ (for some $N \in \mathbb{N}^+$), use a telescoping series to bound $1/a_n$ from above, and hence $a_{n}$ from below for large $n$, and compare $a_n$ to some multiple of $1/n$ for large $n$, thereby showing that a "tail" of the series diverges.  A comment below suggests using the Limit Comparison Test.  If you can get this to work, it would probably lead to a cleaner and more elegant solution.

The assumption that the terms in the series are decreasing seems to be unnecessary.

Your idea ("I have been wondering...") is an interesting one.  Doubtless someone will prove it one way or the other soon.

I don't know if any of the "standard tests" work.  Obviously the Ratio Test fails.

Comment: Your $\frac1{a_n}$ is probably $a_n$ instead.

Comment: (And formalizing your heuristic, one sees that the limit comparison test works.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo : thanks for the correction and for your observation.

Comment: Thank you stefan, I filled the details for your proof and it convinces me... Still wondering about the other idea!

Comment: @Moritzplatz : the assumption that the terms are strictly decreasing is essentially redundant, since the assumption $1/a_{n+1}-1/a_n \to 3$ as $n \to \infty$ implies the terms are decreasing for large enough $n$.  For your "other idea", I spent 15 minutes or so trying to prove the contrapositive, with little progress.

Comment: Infact I did use that to prove that limit, I just repeated it in case it was important, I am looking for counterexamples at the moment...it looks like a pretty strong test (you prove the harmonic series converges immediately) so I think it could not hold....

Comment: @Moritzplatz : you mean that your test shows "the harmonic series _diverges_...", in case anyone is confused by your comment.

Comment: @Moritzplatz : I just noticed that the assumption $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}/a_{n} =1$ is redundant.  It follows from the following: $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, and $1/a_{n+1}-1/a_n \to 1/3$ as $n \to \infty$ (collectively, these are weaker than the assumptions that remain when you remove " $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}/a_{n} =1$".